# Javascript chain switch script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS.

I'm trying to make a simple button, which will switch numbers from 0 to 11. So if current number is 11 next one(after button click) should be 0. Some kind of numbers chain.

Need help!

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can change the initial `number` and `maxNumber` as per your need.

```
var number = 0, maxNumber = 12;
$("input").click(function(){
    $('#num').text((number++)%maxNumber);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gJktD/1/)**

Alternative approach to make @Tomalak happy :).

```
var number = 0, maxNumber = 11;
$("input").click(function(){
    number = number >= maxNumber  ? 0: number+1;
    $('#num').text(number);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gJktD/2/)**

Comment: This will stop to work after 9,007,199,254,740,992 clicks. :)

Comment: I wonder, how much time will it take for so many clicks :). But yes we can a write a different logic to reinitialize the `number` variable.

Comment: I wonder how many mice will wear out in the process. ;)

Comment: A warning: The `number` variable does not reflect the value of the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
var current = 0;
function shift(){
   current = current < 11? current +1: 0;
}

<input type="button" value="change" onclick="shift()" />
```

if there's something you don't understand, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method to accomplish this is by using the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_%28Modulus%29).

1. Initialize a counter at -1.
2. Increment the counter on click, and display the value

HTML (**[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAzkj/)**):

```
<input type="button" id="id-of-button" value="0" />
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var button = document.getElementById("id-of-button");
var counter = 0;
button.onclick = function() {
    counter = (counter + 1 ) % 12; // 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 10, 11, 0, 1, ...
    this.value = counter; // Sets the value of the button to the counter's value
};
```

Comment: Funny that you *say* to initialize the counter from -1, but you don't do it. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak Nicely spotted. I have chosen to initialize at zero, because an initial value of zero was already displayed on the button. If the button's initial value was also set by the script, the counter has to start at `-1` indeed.

Comment: Both the code and the explanation are okay, they just don't match each other. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script suitable for understanding by beginners that uses no special framework:

Note the purpose of this code was to be readable by beginners, so no syntax shortcuts.

**Beginner version**:

Javascript:

```
function next_number(){
  var $count;                                //declare the variable
  $count = document.getElementById("count"); //cache the object holding the count
  if ($count.value == 0) {                   //logic to swap numbers
    $count.value = 11;
  }
  else {
    $count.value = 0;
  }
  return $count.value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="count" value="0" />
<input type="button" onclick="alert(next_number())" value="Click me" />
```

**Using syntax shortcuts**:

Javascript:

```
function next_number(){
  var $count; $count = document.getElementById("count"); 
  $count.value = ($count.value == 0)?11:0;
  return $count.value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="count" value="0" />
<input type="button" onclick="alert(next_number())" value="Click me" />
```

Comment: Don't encourage the use of non-declared variables.

Comment: Hi Rob, I removed the undeclared variable to simplify and it wasn't truly required.

Comment: You should cache the `document.getElementById("count")` variable. Also, more importantly, you have to **increment** the value.

Comment: Hi Rob, he just wanted to flip between 0 and 11, that's what the code does. Can you explain what you mean by caching the count variable ?

Comment: Store `document.getElementById('count')` in a variable, eg: `var counter = document.getElementById('count');count.value = count.value == 0 ? 11 : 0;return count.value;` (the caching part is `var count = ..` and `count.value = ...`.

Comment: Ok, I cached it but I won't use conditional statement shortcut as this is for beginners. Let's give them good programming practices !